# injecting script into jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, xss

i'm new with node.js and jade view engine hopefully someone can help me with this.
So I'm trying to simulate an XSS attack and my task is to build a simple form where someone can submit a comment which will then appear at the same page beneath the form with the list of comments.
So my jade file looks like this:

```
    ul
    each name, comment in cmt
        li= name + ': ' + comment
```

where cmt is my array of comment objects.
the problem is that when I try to inject a simple alert script it appears as plain text.
Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to do? or should I just use regular html files instead of using jade?

Comment: Could you please post your full code here, there aren't enough details to fully help you with your issue.